# .net core 3.1 api file upload error 413 wen i deploy docker image to kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, file-upload, asp.net-core-webapi, amazon-eks

the webservice works just fine on my computer but after it's deployed it doesn't work anymore and throw this error `413 Request Entity Too Large` I added this code to `startup.cs` file

```
services.Configure<FormOptions>(x => 
            {
                x.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
                x.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
                x.MemoryBufferThreshold = int.MaxValue;
                x.MultipartBoundaryLengthLimit = 209715200;
            });
```

but didn't help at all . So after some research I added `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "100m"` to `deployment.yaml` but also didn't help

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider? Also could you attach your yaml? About this error (`413 Request Entity Too Large`) - I found [this solution](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bsd-nginx-413-request-entity-too-large/), could you test it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:
Login server:

> sudo nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

Set:

> client_max_body_size 2M;

This working with me.

Comment: this one works to me.